# Kill docker container created more than x days ago

Tags: docker

I would like to kill all running docker containers older than 7 days.
I could not find a way to easily filter by creation date.
There is a `before` filter to `docker ps` but it only takes another container's id, see documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know of no way to filter by creation date, but you can do some post-processing in the shell or some other scripting language. For example:

```bash
docker ps -f status=running --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedAt}}" | while read id cdate ctime _; do if [[ $(date +'%s' -d "${cdate} ${ctime}") -lt $(date +'%s' -d '7 days ago') ]]; then docker kill $id; fi; done
```

here is the same code refactored to try to be more human readable:

```bash
docker ps -f status=running --format "{{.ID}} {{.CreatedAt}}" \
| while read id cdate ctime _; do
    if [[ $(date +'%s' -d "${cdate} ${ctime}") -lt $(date +'%s' -d '7 days ago') ]]; then
        docker kill $id
    fi
done
```

note: the `prune` commands support filtering on `until` but the `docker container ls --filter` errors out if you try to pass in any `until=5m` for the filter parameter.